Are you allowed to talk about someone’s sins or teach them?
In Islam you have to conceal your brothers sins and not expose it to others, however what if in private are we not allowed to critique them or teach them? What if they done it in public or in front of multiple people are we allowed to critique/teach them in front of said people?
Does anyone know any hadiths related to this?
